# relative import with no known parent package error while importing from different folder

Tags: python, import, python-import

I've a directory structure like this below:

```
ParentPackage/
 childPackage/
    __init__.py
    subpackageOne/
        __init__.py
        moduleA.py
        moduleB.py
    test/
        __init__.py
        test.py
```

I'm trying to import a method "methodX" from moduleA.py to my test.py residing inside test folder.
below is the code which I've tried

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.realpath('..'))
from ..subpackageOne.moduleAimport methodX
```

but getting error "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package".

In addition to this moduleA.py is importing moduleB.py and while running the test I am getting No module named 'moduleB'.

There are already lot of question has been asked on this topic, however suggestions provided for those didn't work for me.

Comment: If you are OK to add the path in your file as you showed, I would suggest to add the absolute path of childPackage and then do absolute import. Relative imports are not so good.

Comment: @Ssayan Thanks a bunch for quick response .i'm very new to Python , could you please elaborate more, also I've updated the question as i am also getting error if moduleA.py is importing moduleB and while running the test.py i am getting " ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "moduleB "

Answer (score 0):

Based on your architecture, you can do that:

```py
import os
import sys
# Assuming your package is on a drive called C:. 
# That is what I mean by absolute path, it needs to refer the path from the disk 
# so it does not depend on where you are
sys.path.append("C:/path/to/childPackage")
# Absolute import is just importing wihtout using dots at the beginning. 
# In this case, python will look for installed packages in your environment
# and then any folder that is in your path.
from subpackageOne.moduleA import methodX
```

If you prefer, you may want to add the parentPackage in your path so you can use any childPackage in case you have several.

```py
sys.path.append("C:/path/to/parentPackage")

from childPackage.subpackageOne.moduleA import methodX
```

**Note**: I see you have `__init__` files in your architecture which suggests you may want to create an installable package that you can build after (using a `setup.py` or `setup.cfg` file). In this case, you could install your package in your virtual environment and then you would not need to add the directory to your path. [setuptools Doc](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html) or [some tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/)